# How do I show the amount of data saved in the json file for my Discord bot?

Tags: node.js

As I mentioned in the title, I made a registration bot and
It saves the name written in json file. How do I show how many of each recorded data is

```
 "database": {
    "member-discord-id": "test",
    "member-discord-id": "test23"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access the json file easily, it's just a simple javascript problem. Here is how you can do this:

```
const database = {
  "member-discord-id1": "test",
  "member-discord-id1": "test23",
  "member-discord-id2": "test23"

}
const databaseValues = Object.values(database) //["test", "test23"]
const numberOfRecordedData = databaseValues.reduce((accumulator, value) => ({
  ...accumulator,
  [value]: (accumulator.value || 0) + 1 // number of values we already counted (or 0 if we haven't counted it yet) + 1
}), {}) 
console.log(numberOfRecordedData)
/*
{
  test: 1,
  test23: 2
}
*/
```

About the reduce(): [Mozilla javascript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Edit: If you just want to know how many records there are in total, you can just do this:

```
const database = {
  "member-discord-id1": "test",
  "member-discord-id1": "test23",
  "member-discord-id2": "test23"

}
const databaseValues = Object.values(database) //["test","test23", "test23"]
const numberOfRecordedData = databaseValues.length()
console.log(numberOfRecordedData)//3
```

Comment: I did what you said It worked but each data is displayed as 1 one by one I want to show how much they all are in total

Comment: You mean how many different values in total ? 2 in this example ?     `{
  "member-discord-id1": "test",
  "member-discord-id1": "test23",
  "member-discord-id2": "test23"
    }`

Comment: I want to show all the values ​​in the file as a single value, so how many records there are, for example, there are 5 records, so I want to show them as one

Comment: Could you provide an example of the output you want

Comment: I mean how many records are in the Json file I want to show them all as one It's like there are 5 records When I use the command I want it to write how many records are in the json file

Comment: My Problem Is Solved Sorry You edited your post I didn't see it